# Parse a number with Java

Tags: java, scanf

I have a string which I assume is a zero padded representation of an integer, of 6 digits, e.g.:

```
"001234"
```

I want to parse it to a Long object, but I want to check that it's exactly the same format; I would like to return errors if it's not of length 6, not zero padded, etc.

In C I would use some variant of scanf. What's the Java way?

Comment: Long.parseLong. But it doesn't give me all I want. I can use regex but it looks like an overkill.

Comment: @RS.. Are you worried about length? Just check the length of the string before parsing. And you're right. You really don't need Regex here.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(s.length() != 6) 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input is not of length 6: " + s);
Pattern allDigits = Pattern.compile( "[0-9]+" );
if(!allDigits.matcher(s).matches()) 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input is not numeric: " + s);
long val = Long.parseLong(s);
```

Comment: No need for the pattern match. Long#parseLong takes care of that. But you probably want to check for `-`.

Comment: I added the pattern match to show how to do the check explicitly.

Comment: Actually you should probably lose the first if and put it in the regex: "^[0-9]{6}$".

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet might help you.

```
   String test = "001234";
    long correctValue = 0;
    if (test.charAt(0) == '0' || test.length() != 6) {
        System.out.println("padded or incorrect length");

    } else {
               correctValue = Long.parseLong(test);             
    }
    System.out.println(correctValue);
```

Comment: I read that as padded when necessary. 123456 does not need it.

Comment: OK may be I interpret it wrong.Thanks for the correction :) I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the trick is that Long.parseLong does not accept no trailing or leading spaces, but accepts leading zeroes, so you need only to check that the length = 6

```
String input = "001234";
if (input.length() != 6) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(input);
}
long l = Long.parseLong(input);
```

Actually it accepts a non zero padded "123456" but I think it corresponds to your requirements.

Comment: +1 for using Integer. Six digits don't need Long. Probably want to check if it's positive, too (depends on requirement)

Comment: oops, will use Long just in case

Comment: You probably meant `IllegalArgumentException` instead of `IllegalAccessException`

Answer (score 1):

A variant of Aleksander Blomskøld's answer:

```
Pattern allDigits = Pattern.compile("^\d{6}$");
if (!allDigits.matcher(s).matches()) 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input is not numeric: " + s);
long val = Long.parseLong(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the String validation in regexp.
if is valid, than I would use `Long.parseLong`

Answer (score 0):

`Long#parseLong` would get you most of the way. Just check that is has six digits, and that the result is positive. It cannot be padded with anything else but 0 (because then the parse will fail).

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean you want to check the length like

```
if (text.length() != 6)
```